# Unable to plot traces in plotly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, data-visualization

I am trying to plot this dataframe:

```
Date Time           Sample Name         Result
2020-08-26 14:34:02 QC Test             0.742
2020-08-26 14:55:24 Myoblast            0.506
2020-08-26 15:12:27 Myoblast DEM        0.607
2020-08-27 15:23:10 CD T2 P1            0.854
2020-08-27 15:25:06 CD T2 P2            0.854
2020-08-27 15:27:32 CD T2 P3            0.831 
2020-08-27 15:47:05 Amy F12             0.894
2020-08-27 16:57:02 CD- T2 P8           0.963
```

I want 'Sample Name' to be on the x-axis, 'Result' on the y axis, and 'Date Time' to be shown on hover.

I have this code:

```
layout = go.Layout(title='Viability Plot',
                   xaxis={'title':'Sample Name'},
                   yaxis={'title':'Viability(%)'})
    
    
fig = go.Figure(layout=layout)


for c in df['Date Time']:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Sample Name'], y=df['Result'],
                             mode='markers',
                             name = str(c)))
```

But for some reason it plots traces on top of each other.. like this:

[image]
[image]

They are literally on top of each other...

Instead, in my case, there is supposed to be one single data point for each Sample Name corresponding to the Result, and labeled as corresponding "Date Time".

Please, help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible by simply defining it in the hover text. In this case, if it is time-series data, it must be converted to a string type.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
"Date Time"           "Sample Name"         Result
"2020-08-26 14:34:02" "QC Test"             0.742
"2020-08-26 14:55:24" "Myoblast"            0.506
"2020-08-26 15:12:27" "Myoblast DEM"        0.607
"2020-08-27 15:23:10" "CD T2 P1"            0.854
"2020-08-27 15:25:06" "CD T2 P2"            0.854
"2020-08-27 15:27:32" "CD T2 P3"            0.831 
"2020-08-27 15:47:05" "Amy F12"             0.894
"2020-08-27 16:57:02" "CD- T2 P8"           0.963
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
df['Date Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Time'])

import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Sample Name'],
                         y=df['Result'],
                         mode='markers',
                         showlegend=False,
                         hovertext=df['Date Time'].astype(str)
                        )
             )

fig.update_layout(title='Viability Plot',
                  xaxis={'title':'Sample Name'},
                  yaxis={'title':'Viability(%)'}
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that it's plotting the entire data set for every datetime.

```
x=df['Sample Name'], y=df['Result']
```

Try changing it to something like this:

```
for c, n in enumerate(df['Date Time']):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Sample Name'][n], y=df['Result'][n],
                         mode='markers',
                         name = str(c)))
```

Comment: Hmm.. I tried but it gives me this error: 
KeyError: datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 26, 14, 34, 2)
Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: I'm so sorry - I put n in the wrong order. it should be for n, c in enumerate(df['Date Time']):   ... I tested this and it should work now

Comment: Let me know if that fixes it. Apologies for the confusion

Comment: Did it work for you? I have just tried it and it gives me this "KeyError: 0". I hope I am not bothering you too much on Friday... :D I do hope your solution will help though.. Maybe there is just a little bug left to fix

Comment: That actually did work for me. Could you send me the code for the dataframe itself? It'd be easier for me to test it

Comment: In doing some more research, I realized it's the way Plotly takes inputs (has to be a tuple for x/y, i figured you would be able to trace them individually by your set up). they are getting overridden because it is definitely mapping the entire dataframe for every datetime, but I'm struggling to find a way to map it once per scatter plot point. I'm going to keep looking, there's got to be a way to do it - but tbh Plotly documentation for this is kinda awful lol

Comment: This is a fairly hacky solution, but the graph *looks* normal for me when I do it like this... gonna keep looking to see if there's a better way, but this at least looks like how you wanted: `for n, c in enumerate(df['Date Time']):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[df['Sample Name'][n],df['Sample Name'][n]], y=[df['Result'][n],df['Result'][n]],
                                mode='markers',
                                name = str(c),
                                ))`

Comment: Joe, I am trying to implement it but still gives me the same error.. What is the best way I can send you my data? I have a dataset and my own code which I use to modify the raw data. We can even have a quick chat to discuss if that's more convenient for you.. Let me know what will work best :) I am so obsessed with making it work!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242869/discussion-between-joe-ridyard-and-mariant).

Comment: Yeah I know the feeling. Do you have a preferred way to communicate? I'd like to dig into the issue a bit more, cause now I want to make it work too lol